# How to remove HTML tags from JSON response

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, angular

For admins: I have checked similar topics here but unfortunatelly I didn't find an answer.

I'm trying to delete all html tags from http GET response.
I have a controller written in ASP.NET MVC which calls a database  procedures. These procedures return json where html tags are present.
An application is written in Angular4 framework. 
I consider what is the best place to strip all html tags and replace them with this tags:

```
& --> &amp;
 < --> &lt;
 > --> &gt;
 " --> &quot;
 ' --> &#x27;     &apos; not recommended because its not in the HTML spec (See: section 24.4.1) &apos; is in the XML and XHTML specs.
 / --> &#x2F;     forward slash is included as it helps end an HTML entity
```

Procedures in MS SQL Database return JSON data this way:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS FOR JSON AUTO
```

MVC Controller receives this string and returns to the application:

```
object response= ExecuteProcedure("GetAllUsers");
return response;
```

In the application I call API this way:

```
getJson(url: string): Observable<any> {
           return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

It's puzzling for me why XSS does not work within the application, but works when I'm calling an API directly from browser. 
I'll be appreciate for all tips.

Comment: What is your version of MSSQL?

Comment: I' using 2017 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
return this.http.get(url).map(res => {
   let theJson = res.json();
   let theString = theJson.stringify();
   return theString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
}).catch(this.handleError);
```

This assumes you don't have any '<' or '>' characters within html outside of the tags

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to remove HTML tags

Description.

1)RemoveHTMLTags(string str) gets the json string.

2. compare the json string with regex "<[^>]*>".
3. if found any HTMl tag remove the tag from the json string.
4. Return Json string free from html tags.

   ```
   public  string RemoveHTMLTags(string str)
    { 
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rx =
        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]*>");
        str = rx.Replace(str, "");            
        return str;
    }
   ```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I hope It will be easy now to understand.